# How to get call status after hung up in twilio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio

I am developing a site where user would be able to call a person using twilio
till now twilio was returning all the call list including no-answer,busy and completed by now it seems that twilio is returning only the completed call list which is causing problems while charging the user on my site.even if the user does not answer the call he is charged according to previous call duration.
so i need the status as soon as the call is ended or the call sid or duration of that call whatever it may be even if not answered.
how can that be done

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sounds like a situation where sending an email to help@twilio.com is the best route.  Please include the CallSids if the calls where the status is not updating.

Hope that helps.

Comment: in twilio logs i can find the status as no answer but when fetching the list programmatically it is returning only calls which have status as completed